# Please identify sci-fi movie by scene description

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg, artificial-intelligence

What I remember is a final battle scene.

- a large transparent pillar in a building/rocket silo, the act happens on its top.
- contains a part of computer core inside, protagonists are aimed at shutting it down
- a huge number of attackers (cyborgs?) is crawling on that pillar and joining the battle.

I watched it in 2011..2013.

Based on the CG quality I remember, it may be a 2007+ blockbuster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds very much like the climatic battle in [I, Robot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0343818/) (from 2004).

Comment: Nanite injection scene, yes. Thanks!